# FileNotFoundException (Permission Denied)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, apache-commons-fileupload

All,
I'm using commons-FileUpload to allow my students to upload their assignments to my server through the class website. It works just fine running tomcat/eclipse on my local machine. However, when testing it on my server I have through digitalocean.com I am getting a FileNotFoundException (PermissionDenied).

Stack trace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
 /uploads/cosc111fall2013/Assignment1/Program1.java (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:209)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:160)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:394)
    at uploadServlet.Uploader.doPost(Uploader.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
```

The offending code:

```
try {
            for (FileItem fi : uploaded) {
                fi.write(new File(saveDirectory + fileName + "_"
                        + FilenameUtils.getName(fi.getName())));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.sendRedirect("/uploadFailed.jsp");
            return;
        }
```

I just chmodded the directories that the program writes to so they are all `drw-rw-rw-`. Any tips?

Comment: probably you meant /uploads/ relative to your app directory and not absolutely ?

Comment: try to login in your PC as administrator.

Comment: I believe that the FileItem class of apache-FIleUpload requires an absolute path, but I'll try as if it is relative.

Comment: @Magicano - I can log into the server as root no problem.

Comment: /uploads/cosc111fall2013/Assignment1 presumably does not exist.

Comment: `/uploads/cosc111fall2013/Assignment1` does exist. Furthermore, I check to see if a directory exists before writing to it, and I create the directory if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was to chmod 777 instead of 666.