# java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Permission denied)

Tags: filenotfoundexception

I am trying to store images into server path like : /opt/4Home_images/
When I run application it throws exception;
Java code is :

```
public static String textFileUpload(FileItem item, String file_name, String folder) {
        if (file_name != "" && file_name != null) {
            Random random = new Random();
            // Creating Folder In Server
             File f = new File("/opt/4Home_images");
            if (!f.exists())
                f.mkdirs();
            // Setting Filename along with system current mill second with
            // random number with ".jpg"
            String path = f + "/" + getFileName(file_name) + System.currentTimeMillis() + Math.abs(random.nextInt())
                    + ".jpg";
            if (saveFile(item, path))
                return path;
        }
        return "";
    }

    // Saving the file with destination path address
    private static boolean saveFile(FileItem item, String des_path) {
        try {
            File savedFile = new File(des_path);
            item.write(savedFile);
            BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(des_path));
            int type = originalImage.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : originalImage.getType();
            ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", new File(des_path));
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }


It throws exception like : 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/4Home_images/49441749f742328289079edf04a850d61443009145430176665345314525770737831330188803.jpg (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:394)
    at org.slv.controller.PropertyController.saveFile(PropertyController.java:507)
    at org.slv.controller.PropertyController.textFileUpload(PropertyController.java:497)
    at org.slv.controller.PropertyController.Update_Property(PropertyController.java:416)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:850)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please format your question and all code therein so that others can read it without hassle. You're more likely to get help like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FileNotFoundException (Permission Denied)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949922/filenotfoundexception-permission-denied)

Comment: You don't have write access to the directory you're trying to create the file in: in this case, the root directory, where you shouldn't be creating files anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the owner of the folder is the same than the onr that runs the java-program. The folder must also be readable.

So maybe you need to set de permissions via shell by using chown and/or chmod.

Comment: Not required. The only requirement is that the directory be writeable by the current user.